# How many reviewers see a given article in the 'First Posts' queue?

Tags: discussion

The 'First Posts' queue is presumably a way to keep noobs on track with best practices by making comments. It also gives the reviewer the opportunity to vote on the question or answer.

My question is if Person 'A' makes a first post and then reviewer 'R' examines it in the queue, is the post also presented to reviewer 'R2'?  If so, how many reviewers will see the first post?

If it is shown only to the person who is working the queue, why is that?  It seems preferable to have *several* people examine it, like the way everything else works.

Answer (score 6):

First posts used to get three reviewers, but it looks like they now get only one. Some people disagree with that decision:

- [Please require more reviewers on First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/please-require-more-reviewers-on-first-posts)
- [“Late Answers” and “First Posts” encouraging unnecessary actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions)
- [First-Post “No Action Needed” should not count to review stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244599/first-post-no-action-needed-should-not-count-to-review-stats)

Comment: I am in the constituency that thinks three reviewers are better than one. Is the proposal still alive?

Comment: @GayotFow I don't know. You could try bringing it up on the Stack Exchange meta. I agree that more than one reviewer does sound like a good idea.